# Ansible- deploy multiple vm with different config

Tags: ansible

I have 2 vsphere and 6 networks(3 applications and different networks for production and stage)  in each vsphere. I would like to deploy a new VM(using vsphere VM template) on this. I confused with the architecture. How can I manage everything in one to deploy multiple VM using one playbook with a different configuration?

Currently, it is working only for one network since the values are hardcoded.

Can anyone please guide me with the architecture. how to manage this

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You could use vars in the playbook, for example if you want differant `template` for each vm you could use it like this: `template: {{ my_template}}` and run the playbook like this : `ansible-playbook someplaybook.yml -e my_template="windows10"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to group VMs in the inventory:

```
[group1]
VM1
VM2
VM3

[group2]
VM4
VM5
VM6
```

Then specify the network info in `vars/group1.yml` and `vars/group2.yml`.

Comment: one more question : How do I maintain inventory ? Each one for product ? or One inventory for all the product ? Please let me know

Comment: I'd have to know more about your environment.  I do prefer to separate inventories for the production, test, and development environments.  (Sometimes there is also an "integration" environment.)  That way, changes to one are less likely to affect the others when you don't want it to.

Comment: As you can see, no line breaks.  Let's try chat.

Comment: I have 6 different application (stage, production, UAT, DEV ) I am confused with the architecture how to maintain with ansible.

I was thinking of the below :
``

├── application-prod.yml
├── group_vars
│   ├── dev
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── rabbitmq.yml
│   ├── stage
│   │   └── rabbitmq.yml
│   └── uat
└── inventory
    └── server_inventory.ini

Comment: i am unable to find you in chat